# SQL inner join combine to one row

Tags: mysql, inner-join, correlated-subquery

With this SQL Query I get a result per meta value, so in this case 2 results at a time. What should happen is that every meta_key is getting it's own column (`user_phone` and `full_name`) with `meta_key` in the row.

```
SELECT * 
FROM invoice_users
INNER JOIN invoice_usermeta 
    on invoice_users.id = invoice_usermeta.user_id 
WHERE meta_key='full_name' OR meta_key='user_phone';
```

I tried a `GROUP BY` but that was not right, and I couldn't understand subqueries...

Database scheme of invoice_users

```
ID | user_login | user_register
--------------------------------
 0    username    [Timestamp]
 1     user2      [Timestamp]
 2     user3      [Timestamp]
```

Database scheme of invoice_usermeta

```
ID | user_id |  meta_key | meta_value
--------------------------------------
 0      0      user_phone   0334234
 1      0      full_name    John Doe
 2      1      user_phone   3453455
 3      1      full_name    Jane Doe
 4      2      user_phone   78678678
 5      3      full_name    John Smith
```

The results I am getting:

```
ID  |  user_login | user_registered |  meta_key | meta_value
 0      username      [Timestamp]     full_name    John Doe
 0      username      [Timestamp]     user_phone   0334234
 1      username      [Timestamp]     full_name    Jane Doe
 1      username      [Timestamp]     user_phone   3453455
```

etc..

What I want

```
ID  |  user_login | user_registered | user_id |full_name | user_phone
 0      username      [Timestamp]        0      John Doe    0334234
 1      username      [Timestamp]        1      Jane Doe    3453455
```

etc

Comment: could you add the result you're getting and what you expect? The database schema would also be helpful here.

Comment: Also, is this for MySQL or SQL Server?  Theyr'e different products.

Comment: Its for mysql @DanField

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The info you provided is a bit sparse, but I will take a stab at it.  What you likely want to do it perform your join twice, like this:

```
SELECT u.*, m1.meta_value, m2.meta_value
FROM invoice_users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN invoice_usermeta m1
    on u.id = m1.user_id 
    and m1.meta_key='user_phone'
LEFT OUTER JOIN invoice_usermeta m2
    on u.id = m2.user_id 
    and m2.meta_key='full_name'
```

If this isn't sufficient because you have many meta values, you would want to investigate whatever the MySQL equivalent is to Sql Server PIVOT(could very well be PIVOT, I just don't know enough about MySQL)

Comment: Updated my main comment. Sorry for the little info, als hard to others about that haha

Comment: I get `Unknown column 'm1.value' in 'field list'` do i have to change these?

Comment: Sorry, but i am very new to SQL, if i ask any weird questions @davejal

Comment: yes, it was just an example, since I didn't know what your schema looked like. I edited it.

Comment: Worked like a charm @BrianRudolp, you used the `LEFT OUTER JOINS` i heard somebody talking about subqueries...

Comment: You don't have to add me to the comments everytime, Brian Rudolph already provided a good answer and edited it accordingly.

Comment: I use left outer joins because otherwise if any user record doesn't have a corresponding meta record for both phone and username, the row would drop out entirely

Comment: @xvilo - also, if this works for you, please accept the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @xvilo - Also, to answer your question about subqueries: They aren't necessary in this context.  You could replicate this logic using subqueries, however joins are the appropriate way to go.  Frankly, I know in SqlServer, if you were to write this query with subqueries, the optimizer would likely compile it to the exact same thing.

Comment: Thanks again @BrianRudolph accepted the answer. Would have given you +2 for the extra answer if that was possible